# Error en Ubuntu 18.04 oracle OCI8

Tags: php, linux, oracle, ubuntu

Hola amigos tengo un error en Ubuntu:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Core Warning
>
> Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (tried:
> /usr/lib/php/20170718/oci8.so (libnnz19.so: cannot open shared object
> file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/oci8.so.so
> (/usr/lib/php/20170718/oci8.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory))
>
> Filename: Unknown
>
> Line Number: 0
>
> Backtrace:

Este error ya lo intente solucionar modifique el archivo 'environment' ubicado en etc/environment de php.

Creo que reinstale oci8 y no funciona igual no esoty seguro si lo hice correctamente.
Cualquier cosa segui estos pasos de esat pagina https://www.cjorellana.net/2020/03/como-instalar-oci8-en-ubuntu-1804-y-php.html

Instale Oracle Instant Client y SDK
Paso 1

Descargue Oracle Instant Client y SDK del sitio web de Oracle. (Necesita iniciar sesión en la página de Oracle)
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html
Descargar
Instant Client Package - Basic
Instant Client Package - SDK
Instant Client Package - Sql Plus (Opcional)
Paso 2

Cree una nueva carpeta para almacenar archivos zip de Oracle Instant Client en su servidor.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/oracle
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/oracle/12.2
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
```

Paso 3

Ahora necesitamos extraer los archivos.

```
sudo cp instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
sudo cp instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
sudo cp instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64

cd /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64

sudo unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
sudo unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
sudo unzip instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip

sudo mv instantclient_12_2 lib
```

Paso 4

A continuación, necesitamos crear un enlace simbólico a los archivos de Instant Client.

```
cd /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/
sudo ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so
sudo ln -s libocci.so.12.1 libocci.so
```

Otra opcion para este mismo paso

```
ln -s /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so
ln -s /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libocci.so.12.1 /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libocci.so
```

Paso 5
Agregue la carpeta a nuestro ldconfig.

```
sudo su -
echo /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf
```

Paso 6

Actualice los enlaces de tiempo de ejecución de Dynamic Linker

```
ldconfig
```

Hecho. Ahora podemos pasar a la siguiente parte.
Instalar paquetes adicionales

Para instalar la extensión OCI8, necesitamos instalar algún paquete adicional en nuestro servidor.
Paso 1

Ejecute estos comandos:

```
sudo apt-get install php-dev php-pear build-essential libaio1
```

Paso 2

Una vez instalado, necesitamos obtener el archivo OCI8. Pero, antes de eso, necesitamos actualizar el canal PECL.

```
sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
```

Luego instalaremos oci8

```
sudo pecl install oci8
```

Cuando se le solicite la ubicación del Instant Client, ingrese lo siguiente:

```
instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib
```

Al finalizar deberia mostrar:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20170718/oci8.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/oci8-2.2.0
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=oci8.so" to php.ini
```

Paso 3

Necesitamos decirle a PHP que cargue la extensión OCI8.

```
sudo su -
sudo echo "extension=oci8.so" >> /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
echo "extension=oci8.so" >> /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

Paso 4

Actualiza el servidor.

```
sudo shutdown -r now

sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```

Comment: Hola! Por favor, incluye en tu pregunta los pasos que seguiste y los archivos que configuraste en su estado actual. Si el enlace se rompe, la pregunta no le servirá a nadie en el futuro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomiendo para ubuntu 18.04 una mejor documentación de la pagina [https://www.galisteocantero.com/como-instalar-oci8-en-ubuntu-18-04/][1]

En esta ocasión vamos a ver cómo instalar oci8 en Ubuntu 18.04. Oci8 es una librería de Oracle para acceder a bases de datos Oracle desde PHP. Puedes leer más información en la web oficial de PHP para oci8 .

En primer lugar, vamos a descargar el paquete básico y sdk del instantclient, al momento de escribir este artítulo son instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip y instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip. Descargamos estos paquetes de la web oficial de la librería oci de Oracle.

Una vez descargados, los descomprimimos en un directorio llamado instantclient_12_2 por ejemplo. El directorio del SDK, hay que meterlo dentro del directorio del paquete básico. Una vez hecho esto, vamos a crear el siguiente directorio:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/oracle
```

Ahora, vamos a mover los paquetes que hemos descomprimido al directorio anteriormente creado:

```
sudo mv instantclient_12_2 /opt/oracle/instantclient
```

Después, cambiamos los permisos del directorio anterior:

```
sudo chown -R root:www-data /opt/oracle
```

A continuación, instalamos (si no lo tenemos ya) las dependencias de la librería oci8:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-dev php-pear build-essential libaio1
```

Ahora, creamos los siguientes enlaces simbólicos:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.12.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so
sudo ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient/libocci.so.12.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient/libocci.so
```

Una vez realizado esto, debemos agregar el directorio de instantclient a los archivos de configuración:

```
sudo echo /opt/oracle/instantclient > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient
```

Si no te deja realizar esto por permisos de usuario, asegurate de que tu usuario está dentro del grupo de root o bien inicia sesión con root con:

```
sudo su
```

Y prueba de nuevo a realizar el paso anterior. A continuación lanzamos:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Cuando termine de ejecutarse el proceso anterior, haremos:

```
sudo pecl install oci8
```

Nos va a preguntar por el directorio donde está la librería instalada y tendremos que introducir:

```
instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient
```

Ahora, debemos activar la librería al archito php.ini de PHP con:

```
sudo echo "extension = oci8.so" >> /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

Y lo mismo al archivo php.ini de Apache:

```
sudo echo "extension = oci8.so" >> /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

Después de ésto, debemos configurar las variables de entorno como sigue:

```
sudo echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\"/opt/oracle/instantclient\"" >> /etc/environment
sudo echo "ORACLE_HOME=\"/opt/oracle/instantclient\"" >> /etc/environment
```

Y lo mismo para Apache:

```
sudo echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\"/opt/oracle/instantclient\"" >> /etc/apache2/envvars
sudo echo "export ORACLE_HOME=\"/opt/oracle/instantclient\"" >> /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Por último vamos a reiniciar Apache para que cargue la nueva configuración:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Y listo, ya hemos terminado. Ya sabemos cómo instalar oci8 en Ubuntu 18.04.

Para probar el funcionamiento podemos crear un archivo llamado test.php con el siguiente contenido:

```
$conn = oci_connect('usuario_oracle', 'pass_oracle', 'IP_SERVER_ORACLE:PORT_ORACLE/schema');
```

Y ejecutarlo desde la consola con:

```
php test.php
```

En caso de que nos muestre un mensaje de este tipo:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/oci8.so (libmql1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/oci8.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/oci8.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in /var/www/html/.....
```

Es porque no se ha ejecutado bien el comando ldconfig, lo volvemos a lanzar:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

También podrías ejecutar el script como sudo:

```
sudo php test.php
```

Pero es mejor volver a ejecutar ldconfig.

**RECOMIENDO INSTALAR SQLPLUS PARA PODER HACER PRUEBAS DESDE LA TERMINAR Y HACER CONEXION HACIA BD DE ORACLE**